# Mounting long reach center pull brake on Marrakesh (or similar disc-braky) frame?

Tags: brakes, touring, touring-bikes

I wanted to build a  commute/touring bike using a existing parts.  I'm considering Salsa Marrakesh or similar frame that's designed for disc brakes.  I'd love to use rim brake 650B wheels I already have.  Is it possible to mount long reach center pull brakes on these frames.

I see holes both on fork and seat stay, which are meant for mounting rack.  Wondering why can't I mount center pull brakes there.

Comment: Why would you buy a frame designed for disc brakes and not use them? Depending on what hubs your 650B wheels are running (depending on the width), there's a decent chance you're going to end up having to replace the hub or buy a new wheel anyway, making the question moot (disc brake rear wheels are 135 mm; rim brake rear wheels are often 130 mm). And at the point of getting one disc wheel, you might as well get both wheels be disc, and resell your existing wheels.

Comment: It's case of my love for these 650b wheels (high-end, built by a one of the best wheel builders around) and how much I like the Marrakesh frame :)

Comment: Well, you're going to have to get over it unless it's a 135 mm rear which it likely isn't 

Comment: The hub on my wheel is in fact Velo-Orange Grand Cru Touring Hub 135mm :)   So, the only part I need to figure out is could I mount long reach center pulls on holes that are present on this frame.

Comment: Yes, but it may kill you if it fails.   https://www.sheldonbrown.com/home-drop.html     If you tried to have calipers long enough, then their braking effect would range from Wishful Thinking down to zero.

Comment: The Marrakesh takes 700c wheels, so it's a moot point. http://salsacycles.com/culture/introducing_marrakesh

Answer (score 2):

As [Sheldon Brown notes](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/650b.html), 650B rims are 19mm further away from the brakes than an equivalent 700c. Given that your frames were designed for disc brakes in the first place, you will have some difficulty in finding rim brakes with enough reach. You might need an unsafe hack -- especially if you are using fenders.

Furthermore, your brake cabling is set up for disc brakes so you'll need to get new braze on guides or use ugly zip ties.

Most people would wonder why you'd go to such lengths to have worse brake performances and worse looks in order to keep your hubs. There are a number of great looking disc brake hubs now available. If you found one with the same spoke count, you could keep your rims.

Comment: Sheldon's hack is documented at   http://sheldonbrown.com/home-drop.html